# Sticky header for scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I was trying to add a sticky header to my scroll view in swift. While I searched, I found an example and I implemented as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.m_scrlvwMAinScroll.delegate = self
    self.initialOffSet = self.m_vwAnchorVw.frame.origin.y
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var newFrame = self.m_vwAnchorVw.frame
    newFrame.origin.y = max(self.initialOffSet, scrollView.contentOffset.y)
    self.m_vwAnchorVw.frame = newFrame
}
```

But here the sticky view (`self.m_vwAnchorVw`) though stood at the top while scrolling, the other scrollview contents **was scrolling over the sticky view not below the view**.

I want the **scrollview contents to scroll below the sticky view when scrolled up**.

What change should I make in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the result of the order in which you added subviews to the `scrollView`'s `contentView` - add the `stickyView` as the last view in the hierarchy (so that it is always rendered on top of the rest of the content).

Comment: Thank u Milan for responding...I am adding the sticky view programatically. also the other contents of scrollview are added dynamically to scrollview. Can i set hierarchy to sticky view then?

Comment: sure, you should be for example be able to jsut use: `contentView.bringSubview(toFront: stickyView)` when you know that all the content is added